# Did I set this integral up correctly?

Tags: calculus

I have a Calculus II question about solids of revolution using cylinder method. I have tried it multiple times but I can't seem to get the correct answer.

> Use the shell method to find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the line $y = 4x + 5$ and the parabola $y = x^2$ about the following lines.
>
> a. ...
>
> b. ...
>
> c. ...
>
> **d. The line $y = 25$**

This is how I set up my integral:

$$\int_0^{25} 2\pi(25-y)\left(\sqrt{y} -\frac{y-5}4\right)\,dy = \frac{6875\pi}6$$

I've switched some parts around but can't seem to reach the right answer; I assume it is just a computational error on my part (as it usually is!).

Comment: Are you forgetting the little piece to the left of the $y$-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky.  The line intersects the parabola at $(5,5)$ and $(-1, 1).$

The equations for the bounded region change at $y=1.$  It's the line and the parabola above $y=1$ but it's just the parabola below.

So the shell method would give:

$$V = \int_1^{25} 2 \pi (25 - y) (\sqrt{y} - \frac{y-5}{4}) \text{ d}y + \int_0^1 2 \pi (25 - y) (2\sqrt{y}) \text{ d}y.$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thanks, you were correct! Though you confused me for a second with that extra 'y' in the first integral.;)

Comment: That was a typo.  Thanks.